# Возникли проблемы с практическим заданием: Удалите все цифры, которые можно найти слева от самой правой цифры 1

Tags: c++, циклы, while

Я начал изучать C++ в университете. Сейчас изучаем циклы. **Задача**: *Ввод: целое число (integer number). Удалите все цифры, которые можно найти слева от самой правой цифры 1.*

Пример:

- Ввод: 314195
- Результат: 95

Или:

- Ввод: 45131005
- Результат: 005

Для этой задачи мы не можем использовать массивы или команды типа string. Однако мы можем использовать математические функции. Также обязательно должно быть условие while/do while.

Я написал код, который находит значения до первой цифры 1, используя % и /. Однако в результате он не работает должным образом, и когда я ввожу что-то вроде 431004, выводится только 4, а не 004. Есть идея сделать иначе: выписывать результат каждого действия (остаток деления) в самом цикле. Но в таком случае цифры будут в обратном порядке (т.е. например, имея 431004, получим 400, а не 004.

Вот мой уже написанный код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number; 
    cout << endl << "Enter integer number: ";
    cin >> number;

    int result;
    int buffer = 0;
    int divider = 10;
    int check = 1;

    do {
        result = buffer;
        buffer = number % divider;
        divider = divider * 10;
        check *= 10;
    } while ((buffer / (check / 10)) != 1);

    cout << endl << "Result = " << result; 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно печатать строки вроде `005`, хранить результат в виде числа - плохая идея. С другой стороны можно печатать цифры исходного числа, если знать место с которого начать:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n; 
    std::cin >> n;

    // ищем p - степень десятки с которой будем печатать хвост числа
    int p;
    for (p = 1; ; p *= 10) {
        if ((n / p) % 10 == 1) {
            // p указывает на единицу, отступаем на шаг назад и выходим
            p /= 10;
            break;
        }
        // проверку можно было бы сделать в заголовке цикла,
        //   но так нет переполнения при работе с большими числами
        if (p > n / 10) {
            // следующий p превысит n, пора закругляться
            break;
        }
    }

    // печатаем цифры от старших к младшим
    // специально сделал через while, хотя for тут удобнее
    while (p > 0) {
        std::cout << (n / p) % 10;
        p /= 10;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.cpp 
>
> $ echo 431004 | ./a.out
> 004
>
> $ echo 314195 | ./a.out
> 95
>
> $ echo 2147483647 | ./a.out
> 47483647
>
> $ echo 2047483647 | ./a.out
> 2047483647
> ```

**P.S.** Думаете, что, запретив строки и массивы, можно принудить работать с числами? Ничего подобного. Вот решение со списком символов на стеке. Обрабатываются числа (строки цифр) любого размера, лишь бы стек не переполнился.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node_t {
    char digit;
    const node_t *prev;
};

void print(const node_t *node) {
    if (node != nullptr) {
        print(node->prev);
        std::cout << node->digit;
    }
}

void print_tail(const node_t *prev) {
    char c;
    std::cin.get(c);
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
        if (c == '1') {
            print_tail(nullptr);
        } else {
            node_t node = { c, prev };
            print_tail(&node);
        }
    } else {
        print(prev);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    print_tail(nullptr);
}
```

**P.P.S.** В предыдущем примере нет цикла `while`. Хочется встроить его в процедуру печати, да список хранит цифры задом наперёд. Поменяем порядок цифр в списке при его создании. Для этого надо будет передавать список в виде двух указателей - на голову и на хвост. В C++ это удобно делать с помощью ссылок на указатели.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node_t {
    char digit;
    node_t *next;
};

void print_tail(node_t *&head, node_t *&tail) {
    char c;
    std::cin.get(c);
    if ('0' <= c && c <= '9') {
        if (c == '1') {
            node_t *head = nullptr;
            print_tail(head, head);
        } else {
            node_t node = { c, nullptr };
            tail = &node;
            print_tail(head, node.next);
        }
    } else {
        node_t *p = head;
        while (p != nullptr) {
            std::cout << p->digit;
            p = p->next;
        } 
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    node_t *head = nullptr;
    print_tail(head, head);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

берите разницу между этим  числом и таким же числом, но  с заменой на нули после последней единицы:

```
int result = number, n = 1;
while (result && result % 10 != 1)
{
    result /= 10;
    n *= 10;        
}    
result = number - result * n;
```